# Selenium - waiting for DevExpress grids to load

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, devexpress

We have a lot of DevExpress data grids on an ASP.Net webpage.
Waiting for a page to load in the following method doesn't wait for DevExpress grids to load:

```
  protected void waitForPageLoad() {
    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
    wait.until(driver -> {
        LOG.info("Current Window State       : "
                + ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState"));
        return String
                .valueOf(((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState"))
                .equals("complete");
    });
}
```

I am struggling to find a way to wait for the grid to load without putting in thread sleeps. In some cases we have a loading pop up that I can handle however in other cases I can't seem to find any way to fully assert that the DevExpress grid has loaded before moving on to the next line of code.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What about `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions`?

Comment: @pburgr I have methods that use ExpectedConditions but the issue with these DevExpress grids is that an element might be displayed or it might be clickable, however the full grid is not loaded or it could still be refreshing and the action is then intercepted randomly. I need to find a way to ensure the whole devexpress grid is loaded to prevent the intermittent failures.

Comment: can you share URL?

Comment: Unfortunately It's internal security software, its deployed locally.